# Background video in HTML5

Tags: html, video

I've read some of the basics about HTML video tags, but can someone explain to me how the NYT report on the Tunnel Creek avalanche displays that background video when the page loads? Or point me to a good tutorial on the subject?

I tried looking at the page source but couldn't quite suss it out.

http://www.nytimes.com/projects/2012/snow-fall/#/?part=tunnel-creek

Comment: It looks like some type of [parallax scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution is to have a look at http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/ though this SO answer [video as site background? HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800813/video-as-site-background-html-5) shows a simple way to roll your own