# How to replace an image called by a menu button with an embedded video

Tags: html, iframe, embedded-video

I'm trying to adapt a web template to fit to my needs. 
The site looks like this one : http://tomcreus.com
At the bottom left there are three buttons (1,2,3) which allow to change the background picture. I want to replace the pics with embedded videos. Is this possible? 
How difficult it is? Which part of the code do I need to post to help?

**EDIT** :

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="current"><a href="images/bg_img1.jpg">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="images/bg_img1.jpg">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="images/bg_img3.jpg">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) tour to get to know how this site works and what it is for. Posting some code would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks!Again, I don't know which part of the code but this is the menu calling the background images. Instead of images I would like to have embedded video?                                               <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="current"><a href="images/bg_img1.jpg">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="images/bg_img1.jpg">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="images/bg_img3.jpg">3</a></li>
     </ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the `video` in side your `anchor` tags like this.

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="current">
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">
            <video width="320" height="270" controls>
                <source src="steve_powell_320_hard.mp4"  type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2">
                <source src="steve_powell_320_hard.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8, vorbis">
                <source src="steve_powell_320_hard.ogv"  type="video/ogg; codecs=theora, vorbis">
            </video>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="images/bg_img1.jpg">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="images/bg_img3.jpg">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Just change the `src` of the `source` elements to a physical video file on your system/server OR give the URL of a video from a website.

**EDIT :**

This [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp) link can be helpful in embedding a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com) video. And [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp) link is for embedding physical video files in your html.

**EDIT :**

Check below two question. You might get some direction from there. It is for `HTML5`

1. [video as site background? HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800813/1184435)
2. [Can you display HTML5  as a full screen background?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3899865/1184435)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it actually embeds it only at the location of the menu and not as an actual background ... the reference to a similar web site again is this one : http://tomcreus.com/

Comment: Do you want to show a video on button click? Instead of the image that gets changed on click of the button currently?