# How to add Video from project directory in the background of Div

Tags: html, css, video

I have a div in which i want to add Video in the background just like the image but i am not getting how to do it..Here is the CSS where i want to add the video..

```
.page-section {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 800px;
    padding: 50px 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.page-section#intro {
   min-height: 400px;    
}
```

and here is the HTML Div..

```
 <div class="page-section">
 </div>
```

I have tried to add video like this but its not working..

```
.page-section#intro {
min-height: 400px;
background: url(Video/Sapno.MP4) bottom center no-repeat;
}
```

Please help me to add the video from css into the background of Div..

Comment: Have a look..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800813/video-as-site-background-html-5

Comment: @Maddy i tried that link but i am not able to do it..Could help me please

Comment: The video url looks suspicious. Sure it's correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hansal, I don't think the `background` property accepts videos as valid urls. They can only take bitmaps, SVG images, colors and gradients as values – it is possible to fake the appearance of a background video by forcing it behind other HTML elements. There is a propery called [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) which takes care of the 'depth' of elements on the page.

You could try something like this (simple `video` tag in HTML5):

```
 <video autoplay loop poster="foobar.jpg" id="bgvid">
 <source src="foobar.webm" type="video/webm">
 </video>
```

You could style the `video` tag like this:

```
video#bgvid {
position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
background: url(foobar.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

Here, the essential part of the `css` is setting the `z-index` of this element to `-100` which ensures it stays in the background allowing other elements to come on top of it. You could try a similar approach with your corresponding `html` elements. Hope it helps.

Comment: OK ..I got your Point .One little clarification ,How can i set height of `<video` tag ..Please help me ..Because the current one that i am using is playing in full screen whereas i want it with height of 4pppx only

Comment: @HansalMehta, you set the height of the `video` tag like any other `html` element. In the `css` I've provided, I set the `min-width` and `min-height`. You can modify that to suit your needs. If it works for you, do mark the answer as accepted so others might also benefit out of it. Thanks

Comment: Ok.I did it by adding  `min-height: 70%;` but now my video is getting reduced/cut from bottom Which i dont want ..How to avoid it and show the full video in `70%` height..Please help

Comment: Any Suggestions on the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/u5uv3khs/2/)

```
.page-section video{

position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
top:0;
width: auto;
min-width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -100;
background-size: cover;

}
```